# Moving the pointer by a given amount in brainfuck

Tags: brainfuck

My array looks like this at the moment, data pointer at the [n]. The code will give a number from 2-10

0 10 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 0 [n] 0

I need to move the pointer to the left by n spaces without disrupting the data between n and the target location. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
----------[+[>-<+]>]<<<<<<<<<<
```

should work. But also, I'd suggest rethinking your data layout to leave more working space between the values you want to avoid "disturbing".

Comment: Thanks so much, this works exactly as I hoped it would!

Comment: Please upvote it or mark it as the accepted answer, then?